# Selector performance to get val() from nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a better more performance way to write this jQuery selector using either jQuery or JavaScript. I'm Mainly looking at selector speed. http://jsperf.com example is a plus.

```
$('#formEdit div input.t:visible').val();

<div id="formEdit">
  <div>
    <input class="t" type="text">
    <input style="display:none;" class="t" type="text">
    <input style="display:none;" class="t" type="text">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i think without jquery is faster, with jquery it easier, but doesn't make much difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some more interesting results based on my testing. I've included the original test and @corroded's tests for convenience. The fastest one uses pure JS.

[jsperf link](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-test-with-val-extraction)

```
var form = document.getElementById('formEdit');
var ts = form.getElementsByClassName('t');
var value;
for (var i = 0; i < ts.length; i++) {
    if (ts[i].style.display != 'none') {
    value = ts[i].value;
    break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` is not supported in IE5 to IE8.

Comment: yep, you can drop in a replacement implementation.

Comment: how is that. 97% faster performance is really impressive. But cross browser support is important.

Comment: +1 for the plain js. was about to try but got too lazy to go and loop through stuff. i had a hunch plain would get it because it didn't need jquery's framework calls

Comment: @Pinkie - added another test with a cross-browser impl of `getElementsByClassName`. 97% slower in this case wouldn't equate to 97% faster, it would be approx `2998%` faster ;).

Comment: @corroded - I agree, plain can be much faster, but until it's something that is visibly slowing down the app which would *very* rarely be the case, going with a framework is a better option.

Comment: i also agree with the framework option because vanilla js can be quite messy in implementing/maintaining

Comment: @anurag That's impressive. I agree about going with a framework for such task. I got to give you the check mark since the question is about performance. @corroded great job too. Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 2):

do you have other input.t classes in other forms??

if not just use

```
$("#formEdit .t:visible").val();
```

here's a jsperf for you:

link: http://jsperf.com/test-for-so

*checked in ff and chrome and mine is still faster*

do you have any other .t classes on your whole page?

Comment: hmm why does it seem faster on mine? probably because im using chrome?

Comment: Actually yours is faster. I'm doing more testing.

Comment: original code is fastest in IE8, other browsers, this one is faster.

Comment: i think he meant my test was faster in his end also

Comment: @corroded, why isn't it faster to specify #formEdit in the selector. I assumed this will narrow down the search to only #formEdit rather then  searching the entire DOM for class t.

Comment: it's faster because what you're doing is looking for #formEdit then looking for all the divs in there and searching in each of those divs for all the class ts. that's a more specific search but you drilled down to it more times than just looking for the t class immediately

Comment: i've edited the jsperf and you'll see that this new one is much faster

Comment: `$("#formEdit .t:visible").val();` is a wrong selector. Remember there's a child div then input. You skipped the child div. Your previous selector is still fastest.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. +1 for that. I'll wait a little longer and give others a chance before accepting the answer.

Comment: it doesn't matter if there's a child div unless you have other .t inputs outside the div and inside #formEdit. it will still look for .t elements inside #formEdit no matter what its container is. that's why i asked if you have other .t classed elements in your whole page

Comment: Yes there are other t classes outside the div. We have multiple divs each with multiple inputs, all inside #formEdit. Only 1 t class can be visible at one time.

Comment: that new one will still work then as long as they're inside #formEdit. that one selects all visible .t in #formEdit.

Comment: @corroded, thanks for the efforts, i will end up going with your solution. Great job. Since the question was about performance, i had to award it to Anurag.